# How to change keyboard shortcut for Chrome's implementation to HTML5 Speech Input API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, speech-recognition

Google Chrome partly implemented HTML5 Speech Input API which is submitted by Google. And Chrome added a keyboard shortcut to it.

For example, you can open vimeo.com and then focus cursor to search field. Press keyboard shortcut "shift + command + .". You see a prompt waiting you to speak something to search Vimeo.

How can I change this keyboard shortcut?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need an extension for that, something like shortcut manager.

Comment: Can I change this shortcut by writing JavaScript codes in a web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac, follow these steps.

- Go to system preferences
- Go to Dictation & Speech
- Click Shortcut and customize it to whatever you want.

I hope this is what you wanted

Comment: Can I change this shortcut by writing JavaScript codes in a web page?

Comment: I don't think JavaScript can change browser/computer settings currently, and I doubt it will be able to any time soon

Comment: JavaScript can do that on Firefox OS. ;-)